# How to Add characters after the first instance of a character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are many similar threads to this one but none, that I've found, hit the nail on the head.

Cell B2 is the ultimate output from the attached screenshot.

Psuedo code is if C2 = negative, then insert `"neg_"` after the first instance of `"_"`, if C2 = positive, then insert `"pos_"` after the first instance of `"_"`.

Appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry all - underscores keep getting deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=REPLACE(A2,FIND("_",A2)+1,0,IF(C2="negative","neg_","pos_"))
```

[image]